# Прилипание полигона при редактировании (Yandex maps)

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Необходимо сделать, чтобы при редактировании полигона его точки прилипали к некоторому предыдущему полигону. При перетаскивании вершины это можно сделать, а как быть при перетаскивании промежуточной метки?

Я делаю так:

```
    polygon.editor.events.add(['vertexdragend', 'edgedragend'], function (event) {
        var model;
        var globalPixels = event.get('globalPixels');
        var coord = self.getPrevPoint(globalPixels); // здесь я получаю нужные координаты
        if (coord) {
            if (model = event.get('vertexModel')) {
                model.geometry.setCoordinates(coord); // это работает.
            } else if (model = event.get('edgeModel')) {
                model.geometry._coordinates = coord; // это не работает! (функции setCoordinates тоже нет)
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: А можно привести более развернутый пример?
К чему хотите "прилепить" вершины полигона?))

Comment: Вершину полигона я хочу прилепить к координатам, которые выдаёт моя функция getPrevPoint(globalPixels). Она получает некоторые глобальные координаты и выдаёт глобальные координаты некоторой достаточно близкой точки. В данном случае я передаю ей глобальные координаты перетаскиваемой вершины и хочу эту вершину переместить по новым координатам. Для перетаскиваемой вершины это получается, а для перетаскиваемой промежуточной точки - нет.

Comment: И всё же мало-мальский рабочий пример тут будет отнюдь не лишний. Вместо поиска решения заниматься созданием кода, который у вас уже и так есть, мало кому захочется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
object.editor.events.add('beforevertexadd', e => e.callMethod('setGlobalPixels', modify(e.get('globalPixels')) ))
```

https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/geometryEditor.Polygon.html#event_detail__event_detail/event-beforevertexadd